# Sca authentication for subscription having free trial

Tags: stripe-payments

when i try to implement a free trial for certain recurring subscriptions referring to this documentation.
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials.
`invoice payment succeed` webhook trigger before user complete 3 factor authentication.
i try with this test card `4000000000003220`

my business logic for whether user subscribed or not was inside this webhook `invoice.payment_succeeded`.so this webhooks triggers before user complete 3 factor authentication.so what is the possible work around for this?is there any other event that can i rely to make user that business logic for subscription works only after confirmation(in case for 3d secure cards).and for other cards as well.
thanks in advance

Comment: For the Invoice that succeeds, is it referring to the initial (no cost) trial Invoice for $0? If so, you can check the amount on the Invoice and if it's 0, ignore that specific event.

Comment: Hi thanks fo the answer.problem is that webhook trigger before user confirm sca . User can close the page.why it trigger before user confirmation when trial period is set?

Comment: There will be a free trial invoice that succeeds without any payment or payment method required. You'd ignore the event if it's for amount: 0.

Comment: that won't work in case of discount 100%

Comment: It will. If you anticipate there being a 100% discount (which isn't in your original question, apologies for the confusion), you can check the discount on the Subscription as well.